# Jackson: export only getters from an interface

Tags: java, json, jackson

I should use jackson to serialize the content of an object to a json string. I want to filter the output using the interfaces I already have. I can explain better with an example!

```
public interface BaseInterface
{
    public String getStringOne();
    public String getStringTwo();
}

public interface ExtendedInterface extends BaseInterface
{
    public String getStringThree();
    public String getStringFour();
}

public class Foo implements ExtendedInterface
{

    public String getStringOne(){return "One";}
    public String getStringTwo(){return "Two";}
    public String getStringThree(){return "Three";}
    public String getStringFour(){return "Four";}

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        String outputJSON;
        Object output1, output2;

        output1 = foo;
        outputJSON = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(output1);
        System.out.println(outputJSON);

        output1 = (BaseInterface) foo;
        outputJSON = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(output1);
        System.out.println(outputJSON);
    }
}
```

What I'd like to have is in the first print is

```
{
    "stringOne": "One",
    "stringTwo": "Two",
    "stringThree": "Three",
    "stringFour": "Four",
}
```

and in the second just the first two getters, according to the interface

```
{
    "stringOne": "One",
    "stringTwo": "Two"
}
```

The problem is that I get the same json as the first print.

Comment: Casting doesn't change the object.

Comment: I know, but if I try to use the getStringThree from an object declared `BaseInterface obj` the compiler say there's an error. I'd like to limit the getter methods jackson can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible with a single class. You're trying to serialize the same object into 2 different json formats. Jackson uses the type of the object, the type's accessors and mutators, and all its annotations to produce the json. Since a type can only have one set of annotations/methods, you can only produce one json format for a given object of that type.

You'll need to create 2 DTO classes: one that implements `BaseInterface` and another that implements `ExtendedInterface`. You can then transfer data between them.

Comment: That's what I wanted to escape! :( The problem is I have only one source that returns me the object that contains the data. Then, depends on the purpose, I'd like to use one set of getters or another(in this case a restrict set). There's a way to do this?

Comment: @user2714602 I don't remember the `ObjectMapper` method, but you should be able to convert your object to a `JsonNode` and add/remove json fields. But that doesn't seem any better than a DTO.

Comment: Ok, maybe there's a way but it coud take too much time to implement. The DTO classes are simpler and they don't take so much code.